# AS3 Panning Multiple MovieClips

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am panning a background but I can not pan Movie Clips that are on that background is there anyway I can pan multiple Movie Clips? Currently I have somthing that looks like this
panning a single Movie Clip how can I pan multiple Movie Clips?

```
world.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, beginPan, false, 0, true); 

function beginPan(e:MouseEvent):void
{    
    deltaX = mouseX - world.x;            
    deltaY = mouseY - world.y;

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doPan, false, 0, true);
    stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endPan, false, 0, true);
}

function doPan(e:Event):void
{
    var curX:int = mouseX - deltaX;
    var curY:int = mouseY - deltaY;

   world.x = curX;
    world.y = curY;

}


function endPan(e:MouseEvent):void
{
    stage.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, endPan);
    removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, doPan);
}
```

Comment: Either add your other clips as children of world, or move other instances (as well as world) in your doPan function.

Comment: You can either add all the MovieClips you want to move into another "Wrapper" MovieClip and still only move one. Or in your doPan() loop through an array of all the MovieClips you want to move and that way you can move them all individually.